# What is the difference between "GNU Autotools" and "Executable" project type in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

When creating a new C/C++ project with Eclipse CDT I get to choose between different project types. Among those are "GNU Autotools" and "Executable" (managed build?).

I have created empty projects with both types.
A difference I noticed is that with GNU Autotools I have less options in the project properties under "C/C++ Build" --> "Settings".

I am using Eclipse CDT version 2022-03 (4.23.0).

When should I choose which project type?